# Add and remove operations on lazily initialized collection behaviour?

Tags: hibernate, jpa, jpa-2.0

im currently trying out JPA 2 and using Hibernate 3.6.x as the engine.

I have an entity of ReceivingGood that contains a List of ReceivingGoodDetail, and has a bidirectional relation. Some related codes for each entity follows :

---

ReceivingGood.java

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy="receivingGood",  
        targetEntity=ReceivingGoodDetail.class, 
        fetch=FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private List<ReceivingGoodDetail> details = new ArrayList<ReceivingGoodDetail>();

public void addReceivingGoodDetail(ReceivingGoodDetail receivingGoodDetail) {
    receivingGoodDetail.setReceivingGood(this);
}

void internalAddReceivingGoodDetail(ReceivingGoodDetail receivingGoodDetail) {
    this.details.add(receivingGoodDetail);
}

public void removeReceivingGoodDetail(ReceivingGoodDetail receivingGoodDetail) {
    receivingGoodDetail.setReceivingGood(null);
}

void internalRemoveReceivingGoodDetail(ReceivingGoodDetail receivingGoodDetail) {
    this.details.remove(receivingGoodDetail);
}
```

---

ReceivingGoodDetail.java :

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "receivinggood_id")
private ReceivingGood receivingGood;

public void setReceivingGood(ReceivingGood receivingGood) {
    if (this.receivingGood != null) { this.receivingGood.internalRemoveReceivingGoodDetail(this); }
    this.receivingGood = receivingGood;
    if (receivingGood != null) { receivingGood.internalAddReceivingGoodDetail(this); }
}
```

---

In my experiements with both of these entities, both adding the detail to the receivingGood's collection, and even removing the detail from the receivingGood's collection, will trigger a query to fill the collection before doing the add or remove.

This assumption is based on my experiments that i will paste below.

My concern is that : is it ok to do changes on only a little bit of records on the collection, and the engine has to query all of the details belonging to the collection ?

What if the collection would have to be filled with 1000 records when i just want to edit a single record ?

Here are my experiments with the output as the comment above each method :

```
/*
    Hibernate: select receivingg0_.id as id9_14_, receivingg0_.creationDate as creation2_9_14_, ... too long
    Hibernate: select receivingg0_.id as id10_20_, receivingg0_.creationDate as creation2_10_20_, ... too long
    removing existing detail from lazy collection
    Hibernate: select details0_.receivinggood_id as receivi13_9_8_, details0_.id as id8_, details0_.id as id10_7_, details0_.creationDate as creation2_10_7_, details0_.modificationDate as modifica3_10_7_, details0_.usercreate_id as usercreate10_10_7_, details0_.usermodify_id as usermodify11_10_7_, details0_.version as version10_7_, details0_.buyQuantity as buyQuant5_10_7_, details0_.buyUnit as buyUnit10_7_, details0_.internalQuantity as internal7_10_7_, details0_.internalUnit as internal8_10_7_, details0_.product_id as product12_10_7_, details0_.receivinggood_id as receivi13_10_7_, details0_.supplierLotNumber as supplier9_10_7_, user1_.id as id2_0_, user1_.creationDate as creation2_2_0_, user1_.modificationDate as modifica3_2_0_, user1_.usercreate_id as usercreate6_2_0_, user1_.usermodify_id as usermodify7_2_0_, user1_.version as version2_0_, user1_.name as name2_0_, user2_.id as id2_1_, user2_.creationDate as creation2_2_1_, user2_.modificationDate as modifica3_2_1_, user2_.usercreate_id as usercreate6_2_1_, user2_.usermodify_id as usermodify7_2_1_, user2_.version as version2_1_, user2_.name as name2_1_, user3_.id as id2_2_, user3_.creationDate as creation2_2_2_, user3_.modificationDate as modifica3_2_2_, user3_.usercreate_id as usercreate6_2_2_, user3_.usermodify_id as usermodify7_2_2_, user3_.version as version2_2_, user3_.name as name2_2_, user4_.id as id2_3_, user4_.creationDate as creation2_2_3_, user4_.modificationDate as modifica3_2_3_, user4_.usercreate_id as usercreate6_2_3_, user4_.usermodify_id as usermodify7_2_3_, user4_.version as version2_3_, user4_.name as name2_3_, product5_.id as id0_4_, product5_.creationDate as creation2_0_4_, product5_.modificationDate as modifica3_0_4_, product5_.usercreate_id as usercreate7_0_4_, product5_.usermodify_id as usermodify8_0_4_, product5_.version as version0_4_, product5_.code as code0_4_, product5_.name as name0_4_, user6_.id as id2_5_, user6_.creationDate as creation2_2_5_, user6_.modificationDate as modifica3_2_5_, user6_.usercreate_id as usercreate6_2_5_, user6_.usermodify_id as usermodify7_2_5_, user6_.version as version2_5_, user6_.name as name2_5_, user7_.id as id2_6_, user7_.creationDate as creation2_2_6_, user7_.modificationDate as modifica3_2_6_, user7_.usercreate_id as usercreate6_2_6_, user7_.usermodify_id as usermodify7_2_6_, user7_.version as version2_6_, user7_.name as name2_6_ from ReceivingGoodDetail details0_ left outer join COMMON_USER user1_ on details0_.usercreate_id=user1_.id left outer join COMMON_USER user2_ on user1_.usercreate_id=user2_.id left outer join COMMON_USER user3_ on user2_.usermodify_id=user3_.id left outer join COMMON_USER user4_ on details0_.usermodify_id=user4_.id left outer join Product product5_ on details0_.product_id=product5_.id left outer join COMMON_USER user6_ on product5_.usercreate_id=user6_.id left outer join COMMON_USER user7_ on product5_.usermodify_id=user7_.id where details0_.receivinggood_id=?
    after removing try selecting the size : 4
    after removing, now flushing
    Hibernate: update ReceivingGood set creationDate=?, modificationDate=?, usercreate_id=?, usermodify_id=?, version=?, purchaseorder_id=?, supplier_id=?, transactionDate=?, transactionNumber=?, transactionType=?, transactionYearMonth=?, warehouse_id=? where id=? and version=?
    Hibernate: update ReceivingGoodDetail set creationDate=?, modificationDate=?, usercreate_id=?, usermodify_id=?, version=?, buyQuantity=?, buyUnit=?, internalQuantity=?, internalUnit=?, product_id=?, receivinggood_id=?, supplierLotNumber=? where id=? and version=?
    detail size : 4
    */
public void removeFromLazyCollection() {
    String headerId = "3b373f6a-9cd1-4c9c-9d46-240de37f6b0f";
    ReceivingGood receivingGood = em.find(ReceivingGood.class, headerId);

    // get existing detail
    ReceivingGoodDetail detail = em.find(ReceivingGoodDetail.class, "323fb0e7-9bb2-48dc-bc07-5ff32f30e131");
    detail.setInternalUnit("MCB");
    System.out.println("removing existing detail from lazy collection");
    receivingGood.removeReceivingGoodDetail(detail);
    System.out.println("after removing try selecting the size : " + receivingGood.getDetails().size());
    System.out.println("after removing, now flushing");
    em.flush();
    System.out.println("detail size : " + receivingGood.getDetails().size());
}

/*
    Hibernate: select receivingg0_.id as id9_14_, receivingg0_.creationDate as creation2_9_14_,  ... too long
    Hibernate: select receivingg0_.id as id10_20_, receivingg0_.creationDate as creation2_10_20_,  ... too long
    adding existing detail into lazy collection
    Hibernate: select details0_.receivinggood_id as receivi13_9_8_, details0_.id as id8_, details0_.id as id10_7_, details0_.creationDate as creation2_10_7_, details0_.modificationDate as modifica3_10_7_, details0_.usercreate_id as usercreate10_10_7_, details0_.usermodify_id as usermodify11_10_7_, details0_.version as version10_7_, details0_.buyQuantity as buyQuant5_10_7_, details0_.buyUnit as buyUnit10_7_, details0_.internalQuantity as internal7_10_7_, details0_.internalUnit as internal8_10_7_, details0_.product_id as product12_10_7_, details0_.receivinggood_id as receivi13_10_7_, details0_.supplierLotNumber as supplier9_10_7_, user1_.id as id2_0_, user1_.creationDate as creation2_2_0_, user1_.modificationDate as modifica3_2_0_, user1_.usercreate_id as usercreate6_2_0_, user1_.usermodify_id as usermodify7_2_0_, user1_.version as version2_0_, user1_.name as name2_0_, user2_.id as id2_1_, user2_.creationDate as creation2_2_1_, user2_.modificationDate as modifica3_2_1_, user2_.usercreate_id as usercreate6_2_1_, user2_.usermodify_id as usermodify7_2_1_, user2_.version as version2_1_, user2_.name as name2_1_, user3_.id as id2_2_, user3_.creationDate as creation2_2_2_, user3_.modificationDate as modifica3_2_2_, user3_.usercreate_id as usercreate6_2_2_, user3_.usermodify_id as usermodify7_2_2_, user3_.version as version2_2_, user3_.name as name2_2_, user4_.id as id2_3_, user4_.creationDate as creation2_2_3_, user4_.modificationDate as modifica3_2_3_, user4_.usercreate_id as usercreate6_2_3_, user4_.usermodify_id as usermodify7_2_3_, user4_.version as version2_3_, user4_.name as name2_3_, product5_.id as id0_4_, product5_.creationDate as creation2_0_4_, product5_.modificationDate as modifica3_0_4_, product5_.usercreate_id as usercreate7_0_4_, product5_.usermodify_id as usermodify8_0_4_, product5_.version as version0_4_, product5_.code as code0_4_, product5_.name as name0_4_, user6_.id as id2_5_, user6_.creationDate as creation2_2_5_, user6_.modificationDate as modifica3_2_5_, user6_.usercreate_id as usercreate6_2_5_, user6_.usermodify_id as usermodify7_2_5_, user6_.version as version2_5_, user6_.name as name2_5_, user7_.id as id2_6_, user7_.creationDate as creation2_2_6_, user7_.modificationDate as modifica3_2_6_, user7_.usercreate_id as usercreate6_2_6_, user7_.usermodify_id as usermodify7_2_6_, user7_.version as version2_6_, user7_.name as name2_6_ from ReceivingGoodDetail details0_ left outer join COMMON_USER user1_ on details0_.usercreate_id=user1_.id left outer join COMMON_USER user2_ on user1_.usercreate_id=user2_.id left outer join COMMON_USER user3_ on user2_.usermodify_id=user3_.id left outer join COMMON_USER user4_ on details0_.usermodify_id=user4_.id left outer join Product product5_ on details0_.product_id=product5_.id left outer join COMMON_USER user6_ on product5_.usercreate_id=user6_.id left outer join COMMON_USER user7_ on product5_.usermodify_id=user7_.id where details0_.receivinggood_id=?
    after adding try selecting the size : 5
    after adding, now flushing
    Hibernate: update ReceivingGood set creationDate=?, modificationDate=?, usercreate_id=?, usermodify_id=?, version=?, purchaseorder_id=?, supplier_id=?, transactionDate=?, transactionNumber=?, transactionType=?, transactionYearMonth=?, warehouse_id=? where id=? and version=?
    detail size : 5
    */
public void editLazyCollection() {
    String headerId = "3b373f6a-9cd1-4c9c-9d46-240de37f6b0f";
    ReceivingGood receivingGood = em.find(ReceivingGood.class, headerId);

    // get existing detail
    ReceivingGoodDetail detail = em.find(ReceivingGoodDetail.class, "323fb0e7-9bb2-48dc-bc07-5ff32f30e131");
    detail.setInternalUnit("MCB");
    System.out.println("adding existing detail into lazy collection");
    receivingGood.addReceivingGoodDetail(detail);
    System.out.println("after adding try selecting the size : " + receivingGood.getDetails().size());
    System.out.println("after adding, now flushing");
    em.flush();
    System.out.println("detail size : " + receivingGood.getDetails().size());
}
```

Please share your experience on this matter !

Thank you !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> In my experiements with both of these entities, both adding the detail to the receivingGood's collection, and even removing the detail from the receivingGood's collection, will trigger a query to fill the collection before doing the add or remove.

If you are "touching" the collection, Hibernate understands that you want access to the elements, and it'll trigger the "lazy initialization". And as you saw, Hibernate is issuing one query for each item in the collection. You can avoid this by setting the batch-size:

http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/performance.html#performance-fetching-batch

> What if the collection would have to be filled with 1000 records when i just want to edit a single record ?

Don't deal with the collection. You are using "mappedBy", which means that the owning part of the relationship is the "one" part, not the "many". So, just set the ReceivingGood in ReceivingGoodDetail to null.

One more thing: I assume that ReceivingGoodDetail is part of the ReceivingGood. I believe that a Set is a better fit than a List in this case.

Comment: partenon: So, if im not using the collection, that means im dealing with the detail only which basically does something like this : getting the existing detail -> update/remove -> merge/remove it using entityManager, skipping the receivingGood.addReceivingGoodDetail. And for adding, create the detail entity -> populate the entity -> add it into the collection with receivingGood.addReceivingGoodDetail will not trigger the whole query from the collection. So the temporary conclusion is to use em on modifying / removing the detail, and use the collection only on adding new detail entities ?

Comment: partenon: About using Set over List is something im confused about. I understand that using Set is more suitable since all records in the db should be unique, but i wonder why would one use List instead. But currently i choose List over Set because as i've read (not yet tested), only List can be sorted with the @OrderBy, and that annotation is not working on Set (depends on the JPA implementation). Please share your view on this ..

Comment: Oops, forgot to use the @ prefix in the previous 2 comments.

Comment: No, you don't need to touch the collection even when inserting a record. You can just call `detail.setReceivingGood(parent)`. `List` with no index has "bag" semantics. When dealing with databases, a bag is rarely used. About `Set`: a "pure" `Set` means that the order is not relevant (contrary to `List`). I believe, though, that you can use a `@OrderBy` on a `LinkedHashSet`, and Hibernate will do the right thing.

Comment: I think i have the basic idea how to not to trigger lazy loading unecessarily. I'll experiment on the LinkedHashSet also. Thank you !